# How to display messages from kernel module without using dmesg?

Tags: kernel, dmesg

In order to display the messages loaded into a kernel module, I can use the command

```
dmesg
```

Is there any alternatives for this command? How this function gets all these kernel messages?

Comment: The easiest way to find out is probably by looking at the source - you can get it from ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.22/util-linux-2.22.1.tar.gz Look in sys-utils/dmesg.c. You'll notice it's checking /dev/kmsg and using the klogctl call (see http://linux.die.net/man/3/klogctl for an explanation of how kernel logging works)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All messages you can see with `dmesg` are by default written to `var/log/syslog` as well. So you can look through this log file with any tool you like.

I use `less var/log/syslog` for reading it later or `tailf var/log/syslog` for "just in time" purposes.

As **zwets** has just pointed out:  `/var/log/dmesg`contains the dmesg output collected during system boot.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there are two another ways.
The first one is

```
cat /proc/kmsg
```

And the second is using 
`'Ctrl + Alt + Fn'` to switch to virtual console.
Then every kernel message(include inserting kmod) will be printed on the screen.